# Magento product page stops rendering. No errors

Tags: magento

I'm having a problem on a Magento product page. The page just stops rendering part way through.

By deleting parts of the view.phtml file I have traced the problem back to this line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
```

Removing that line allows the page to render. My template is using the base/default media.phtml file so I don't see any problems with this.

I can't get any meaningul errors out of Magento. I have error logging enabled in the back end, have moved `errors/local.xml.sample` to `errors/local.xml` and have enabled `display_errors` in `index.php`. I'm a bit stuck now.

Comment: Have you checked the /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Comment: You can modify .htaccess file to enable/disable developer mode via the MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE flag:
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true". 

Also, you can turn on template hints; this might give you more context.

Comment: How are you implementing xml updates? Are you copying over "catalog.xml" to `app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourTheme/layout`, using local.xml or overwriting stuff in either the `base/default` or `default/default` layout folders? Check your product view page xml and make sure the "media" block still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
Also noticed that the images are not uploaded in admin.
So I started digging and figured out that the die happens in:
**/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php**

```
                throw new Exception("Required PHP extension '{$value}' was not loaded.");
```

Somehow and I still cannot figure out, the exception was not shown, so I changed it to echo and it was about gd extension.
So after a simple **apt-get install php5-gd** all became working!